# Otimizar query MySQL para retirar FILESORT

Tags: mysql

Estou no processo de otimização das minhas queries do meu web app. Mas como não tenho muita experiência não consigo encontrar uma solução para remover o uso do FILESORT.

Alguém tem ideia do que fazer para acabar com esse FILESORT? Quais indices criar?

```
SELECT `essences`.*, `brands`.`name` as brand_name, `brands`.`sigla`
FROM (`essences`)
INNER JOIN `brands` ON `brands`.`id` = `essences`.`brand_id`
WHERE essences.published = 1
ORDER BY `essences`.`name` asc
```

#### EXPLAIN

```
id select_type table    type possible_keys key  key_len ref                  rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      brands   ALL  PRIMARY       -    -       -                    11   Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      essences ref  name          name 4       receitadiy.brands.id 69   Using index condition
```

#### Tabela `brands`

```
CREATE TABLE `brands` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`description` TEXT NULL,
`sigla` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`published` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `name` (`name`, `published`)
)
```

#### Tabela `essences`

```
CREATE TABLE `essences` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
`brand_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`tag` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`desc` TEXT NULL,
`alert` TINYINT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`alert_color` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`alert_notes` TEXT NULL,
`preco_ml` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
`published` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `tag` (`tag`),
INDEX `name` (`brand_id`, `name`, `published`)
)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0050)

Comment: Precisa mesmo de dois `ORDER BY` ? Experimenta tirar esses carinhas ai...

Comment: Eu posso tirar apenas um dos order by... mas o order by essences.name precisa ficar lá. @Jorge B não entendi, tem um index para o brands.id lá.

Comment: Isole somente o name aqui: INDEX `name` (`brand_id`, `name`, `published`)

Comment: Acho que Mysql deve fazer um filesort porque vc indica ele deve fazer um ORDER BY sobre "essence" mas ele não tem index para isso. Tenta colocar um index sobre "essence".

Comment: @gmsantos se eu utilizar apenas INDEX name (name) o número de rows no EXPLAIN fica igual ao número de registrados da tabela 'essences'. Aqui tem o link para o [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0050/1)

Comment: http://venublog.com/2007/11/29/mysql-how-to-avoid-filesort/

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu tentei mudar a query com as sugestões do link mas mesmo assim não consegui me livrar do filesort.

Comment: Também estou a tentar resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Em teoria, ele está precisando de filesort porque não possui indice no campo do order by.

Criando um indice isolado na coluna `name` deve remover o filesort.

Answer (score 1):

coloca um indice no puplished assim:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`essences` 
ADD INDEX `published` (`published` ASC);
```

E terá uma consulta aperfeiçoada, verá que o problema é o *ALL* que é um fullscan na sua tabela, então com o indice no published você já não precisará dar esse fullscan, então é uma melhora significativa na consulta

```
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  essences    ref name,published  published   2   const   1   "Using where; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE  brands  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test.essences.brand_id  1   NULL
```

Outra coisa, eu fiz o teste sem usar o join, na verdade nunca precisei usar join em lugar nenhum, há quem diz que o join é melhor que uma sub-query, mas nesse caso por exemplo será mesmo necessário? eu fiz assim a consulta:

```
    explain 
SELECT `essences`.*, `brands`.`name` as brand_name, `brands`.`sigla`
FROM `essences`,`brands` 
WHERE 
`brands`.`id` = `essences`.`brand_id` and
`essences`.`published` = 1
ORDER BY `essences`.`name` asc;
```